# Using $compile in $on function not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function inside my directive as such :

```
      $scope.showUsers = function (groupId) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast("rCube-usermgr-user-list-show", 
                      {id:groupId});
                console.log("inside usergroupitem"+groupId);
            };
```

which sends a broadcast when the user clicks the button and showUsers will be executed.

this is the tpl file with the ng-click:

```
<li class="list-group-item">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1">{{ group.name }}</div>

    <div class="col-md-4"><label>{{ group.description }}</label></div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
                <md-icon-button ng-click="showUsers(group.id)">
                    <md-icon md-font-icon="fa-user-plus" class="fa md-mini"></md-icon>
                </md-icon-button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
                other buttons
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

The group id is caught in a $on function in the controller :

```
 (function (module) {
'use strict';

module.controller('userGroupList', function ($scope, rCubeUiTopics, groupService, $compile, $rootScope) {

    $scope.$on('rCube-usermgr-user-list-show', function (events, args) {
        console.log("args value" + args.id);

        var parent = angular.element('#group-details-container');
        parent.empty();
        var element = $compile('<usermgr-user-list groupId='+args.id+'></usermgr-user-list>')($scope);
        parent.append(element);
    });

});

})(angular.module('r-cube-user-mgt.user-group'));
```

However when the usermgr-user-list is loaded it doesnt pass the group id is undefined. Can $compile only be used in the link: of a directive? What am I doing wrong?

and this is my usermgr-user-list directive :

```
module.directive('usermgrUserList', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:{
            groupId : '='
        },
        controller: function ($scope, userService) {

                  //call method and pass group id 



        },
        templateUrl: 'r-cube-user-mgt/user/list/list.tpl.html'
    };
});
```

where i need the group id to call a method. but the group id is undefined. Can anyone tell me what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope parameters are defined using camel case: `groupId` but in the html you should use dashes, i.e. `group-id`

i.e. :

```
var element = $compile('<usermgr-user-list group-id='+args.id+'></usermgr-user-list>')($scope);
```